# Cant import Table Container in ReactJS - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a table component but cant import TableContainer Component from material-ui:

```
Attempted import error: 'TableContainer' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'.
```

I require it at the top of the page like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TableRow, TableHead, TableContainer, TableCell, TableBody, Table, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
```

And here is my package.json and i tried npm install && npm update too.

```
{
  "name": "link_validator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.7.1",
    "@material/button": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try npm delete and then reinstalling it because it works without an issue for me. Check it out here - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7cv04

Comment: try removing TableContainer from destructured import and import it directly - `import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';`

Comment: I confirm that this problem exists if the version is 4.7.0,  but it is working in version 4.8.0 which you have already. So be sure if you really have  4.8.0

Comment: @AtinSingh
 i tried npm uninstall and installing again with writing latest to package.json + importing without destructuring, it worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

As @AtinSingh suggested  i tried npm uninstall and installing again with writing latest to package.json + importing without destructuring, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I run `npm i @material-ui/core --save` and fix my problem. My version now is 4.9.9